# Get notified when a file got uploaded to server by email

Tags: php, linux, server

my server is hacked and I want a  script or anything to get notified by email when any file uploaded or modified in my website 
I looked at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196640/get-notified-when-a-file-got-uploaded-to-server
and 
[Best way to monitor file system changes in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381566/best-way-to-monitor-file-system-changes-in-linux) 
But I didn't understand the way
can you guide me step by step please ?

Comment: Sorry, but it is impossible to answer to such a broad question in the question and answer style used here. And a general note: your primary goal should be to prevent that such things happen, so to secure your system! So the primary question here is: _how_ did it happen that someone else modified your files and how can you prevent that in future.

Comment: after I looked at access log I figured out how he/she hacked my website 
but I'm not sure is it's the only way 
so that i need to know if there any script notify by email me when any file uploaded to my website so i can fix the problem ASAP and prevent the hacker to do anything to my website , database and my server

Comment: The only way I can think about is to have a cron job creating a checksum over all relevant files and compare that against the previous version. If it differs that means _something_ has changed, why ever. The details of what is possible and how depend on your environment, you will have to add a lot of details to the question.

Comment: I mean for example :
when someone exploit any file in my website and upload a shell on it 
I got notification that there is a new file in my website folder + the path of this file ,
result example : 
`new file uplodaed path /public_html/images/shell.php `

Comment: Yep, we understood what you are looking for. I gave you a hint on how to do it. And asked for more details about your environment. Not about what you want to do...

Comment: my server is Linux OS Centos if that what you mean by environment . sorry if I misunderstood your question

Comment: So it is your own system? That you have administrative control over? Great! Then as said: you need to configure a cron job that executes in a periodic manner. That job executes a script in whatever language you prefer. That script computes a checksum over all your relevant files, something like that: `find somedir -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sort -k 2 | md5sum`. The final sum has to be stored. If the new value differs from some old value, then something has changed. You also can do that separately for all files obviously.

Comment: yes it's my own VPS , and as i see i must to do corn job for all my files right ?

Comment: One cron job which creates one checksum over all files in a folder and, if you insist, one separate checksum for each file inside that folder. I personally would not check every single file. If _anything_ has been modified you should simply roll back to the last backup.

Comment: can you guide me please how can I do it ?

Comment: As said initially: it is not possible here to explain in detail all steps required. You are expected to be able to use your system, this is a place to ask _specific_ questions. You have all the steps required. If one single step is unclear, then read about it, ask, but in a _specific_ manner. No one here wants to write an endless explanation about every details of your system, sorry.

Comment: ok sorry about that and thank you for your time .
accept my apologize please

Comment: All fine, do not get me wrong there. As said: if you have _specific_ questions, ask them. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution, which also keeps backups of my own changes to the CMS.  It works for all the websites I manage (about a dozen, some flat HTML, some Joomla, some Wordpress, on a few different hosts.  This has saved me dozens of times, from user error ("hi, I updated my wordpress template and now the whole site is broken") to server-wide hacks ("dear hosting customer, our Plesk was hacked recently, please change all your passwords and check the contents of your sites").

The only requirement : you need access to a Linux machine which is on at least once a day.  For me it's the desktop I use every day, but you could run this on your web server itself.

Anyway, here it is:

- set up all your FTP sites as bookmarks in `lftp`
- set up local git repositories for each of the sites you host (`git init && git commit -m "first commit"`)
- make sure that cron is running (on most systems it is), and that it can email you the results of each job (you'll probably have to redirect you@localhost to your public email address)
- add this line to `crontab`

`51 03 * * * ~/bin/updateMirrors.sh`

- and save this file as ~/bin/updateMirrors.sh

  ```
  #!/bin/bash    
  # step through the list of FTP bookmarks, mirror each one.
  # seems to take anywhere from 2 to 10 hours
  # cron should email the results to you@localhost

  while read SITE; 
    do NAME=`echo $SITE|cut -d' ' -f1`;
    echo $NAME `date` ;
    cd ~/$NAME/httpdocs;
    # if there's hackage, try this without the -X *-cache-* lines (someone might evilly install a trojan that looks like a cache file)
    lftp $NAME -e "mirror --verbose -X *-cache-*;quit"|grep -E "Transfer|Permission";
    git add . && git commit -m "updateMirrors.sh"
    echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  done <~/.lftp/bookmarks

  ## if you find hackage, do this:
  ## git log --name-only
  ## git checkout [last uuid before hacking started]
  ## lftp and mirror -eR --exclude .git*
  ```

For the last couple of years, every single morning, I get an email in my inbox which looks like this :

```
wecan.be Tuesday 29 November 05:15:59 AEDT 2016 On branch master nothing to commit, working directory clean
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
handyWarhols Tuesday 29 November 05:17:46 AEDT 2016 On branch master nothing to commit, working directory clean
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
colbourneave Tuesday 29 November 05:17:53 AEDT 2016 Transferring file `components/com_content/models/cache.db'
Transferring file `logs/error.php'
[git_head 657d5dc] updateMirrors.sh
 2 files changed, 141 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can see that the error log was updated for one site.  If one of those sites is hacked, it's obvious because there are new files checked in (which I can roll back once I've worked out how it happened).  And whenever I or anyone else add content to any of the sites, or if I update a plugin or template, the new files are checked in.